# How can I access a component prop from parent inside the script tag in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I am just starting with Svelte.
I have a searchbar component and an unique instance of that component: main_searchbar. I want to focus that component from a different component.

**So I export input in searchbar.svelte:**

```
<script>
    export let value = '';
    export let input;
</script>

<span class="searchbar">
    <input
        class="search"
        type="text"
        name="search"
        bind:value
        bind:this={input}
    >
</span>
```

**Then I import it in main_searchbar.svelte:**

```
<script context="module">
    import Searchbar from './searchbar.svelte';
    export let obj;
</script>

<Searchbar bind:this={obj}/>
```

**Then I create a button to focus:**

```
<script>
        import {obj} from './main_searchbar.svelte';

        function focus() {
            obj.input.focus();
        }
</script>

<button on:click={focus}>Focus</button>
```

And last the App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Main_searchbar from './main_searchbar.svelte'
    import Focus from './focus.svelte'
</script>

<Main_searchbar/>
<Focus/>
```

Of course this doesn’t work:
https://svelte.dev/repl/c4eb67950c6240e593173431edb18e1a?version=3.38.2

What is the correct way of doing this in Svelte?

Comment: How would svelte know what `obj` points to? If you have more than one instance of searchbar.svelte, which one gets the focus? I think you should either opt for a store or dispatch an event.

Answer (score 2):

To fix your problem, you can add the following line to `Searchbar.svelte`:

```html
<svelte:options accessors/>
```

But something feels very "un-svelte" about your setup. If I were you, I would reconsider the architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Svelte ships with [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store), a pretty neat way to manage global state; with these, you don't have to pass references between components. Here's a simplified solution using a writable store:

**store.js**

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
// An observable string value.
export const focused = writable('');
```

**searchbar.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import { focused } from './store'
    export let target;
    let input;
    
    // When the value of the "focused" store is equal to target, 
    //    call focus() on the input.
    focused.subscribe((v) => {
        if(v === target) {
            input.focus()
            // Because subscribe only notifies us of changes,
            //   we have to reset the store or the focus button 
            //   will stop working.
            focused.set('');
        }
    })
</script>

<span class="searchbar">
    <input bind:this={input} />
</span>
```

**focus.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import { focused } from './store';
    export let targeting;
        
    // Use the .set() method to set the value of our `focused` store,
    //   triggering all our subscribers (like the one in searchbar.svelte).     
    const focus = () => focused.set(targeting)
</script>

<button on:click={focus}>Focus</button>
```

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import Searchbar from './searchbar.svelte'
    import Focus from './focus.svelte'

    // target and targeting must match. 
    // This allows you to reuse the focus component!
</script>

<Searchbar target="search" />
<Focus targeting="search" />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e9d8a163a3dd44f7b57931c4f73148bc?version=3.38.2)